# Encountered an unexpected error from Waterline in (pretty much) identical create's

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Running the following code to create a new Database (PostgreSQL 11.3) row:

```
const supplier = await Supplier.create(
      Object.assign({}, entityData, {
        last_activity_date: sails.services.datehelper.GetTimeNow(),
        account: supplierParams.supplier,
        monitored: !!activeRegistry,
        verified: true
      })
    );
```

```
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
    at new WLError (invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLError.js:25:15)
    at invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/model/lib/defaultMethods/save.js:188:17
    at invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:550:17
    at invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:544:17
    at _arrayEach (invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
    at Immediate.taskComplete (invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:543:13)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some additional logging (finally in the correct place) in invoice-portal/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/model/lib/defaultMethods/save.js to catch all of the saved data and it was not the creation of the Supplier that failed but the insert of invoice row item (which happens after supplier is created/updated).

Some timing/correlation glitch makes Sails throw the error after the Supplier is created (probably at the end of the transaction) why I was looking at the wrong place... Fixing the validation error for the Invoice Item data solved the issue!